# How do I decrease the temporal interval of JxBrowser and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, while-loop, jxbrowser

Good day!

I use jxBrowser (6.0.2) to show HTML from JavaSwing desktop application. It works but I found the following "feature". If JavaScript contains an error like "while (true) { ... }" page becomes unresponsive however all standard browsers allow to stop this script after very small period of time (10-30 sec). JxBrowser does similar procedure after 8 minutes. Also memory leak occurs (~1.7 Gb).

**Does everybody know how the response temporal interval (8 minutes) can be decreased?
How does JxBrowser log similar situations when page becomes unresponsive?
Does some java-callback exist which allows my swing-application to know that my HTML page becomes unresponsive?**

***My HTML-page:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Loader</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                console.log("xxxxx");
            } catch (exception) {
                alert(exception);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<body id="body1">
    <button onclick="myFunc()">Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

***My java code:***

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.LoggerProvider;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        LoggerProvider.getBrowserLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);
        LoggerProvider.getIPCLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);
        LoggerProvider.getChromiumProcessLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);

        Browser browser = new Browser();

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Browser One", new JButton ("xxxx"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Browser Two", new BrowserView(browser));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        browser.loadURL("#######/Main.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly address your problem but just so you know, you should put your `<script>` tag *inside* of the `<head>` or `<body>`. It's invalid HTML otherwise (although many engines will run it anyway).

Comment: Why are you even running a while (true) infinite loop? That would be bad in ANY event. And, if the browser doesn't cope with it appropriately, then that's a browser issue. Look in its settings section for scripting to see if you can tweak it at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have no problems with HTML. It's not a production code. It's just an example. I use while without break, because it's a model which allows me to simulate unresponsive state of the HTML page.